# validate the data and do either update or insert

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server

This is my file content

id,invocienumber,accountnumber,billstartdate, billenddate,amountdue,status,billdate

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class ReadFromTextFile {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            String lineRead = null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            FileReader fr = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        String sql = "";
            try {
                  System.out.println("--Reading File--");
                  fr = new FileReader(new File("C:/Users/605798364/Desktop/SEMP REQ/InvoiceSummary.txt"));
                  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
                  conn = getConnection();
                  stmt = conn.createStatement();
                  while ((lineRead = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println("Reading Insert Statement : \n" + lineRead.toString());                           
                        sql = lineRead.toString();
                        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                        System.out.println("--Query Executed successfully-- Data Inserted");
                  }
            }catch(SQLException se){
                se.printStackTrace();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                  e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                  try{
                  if(stmt!=null)
                      conn.close();
                  if(conn!=null)
                       conn.close();
                }catch(SQLException se){
                  se.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("--Connection Closed Successfully--");
            }
      }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception 
    {
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "root123";
        Connection conn = null;
        try{
            System.out.println("--Reading DB Connection--");
            Class.forName(driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username, password);
            System.out.println("--Connection established successfully--");
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.println("Error : " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }

}
```

`
My program should read the text file and insert record in db. Before insert check if record already exists for “Invoicenumber”, if exists then update rather than insert
How to do update?

`

Comment: Try to make another method having DB functionality. Because reading file and reading DB in same method is not recommended.

Comment: I have DB functionality in another method only.. not in same method.

Comment: Could you please help me for check condition?

Comment: It's simple boss. After Reading insert statement you need to get Invoice number. Then execute the select statement on that. if your get value then execute update else insert.

Comment: strUpdate = new StringBuffer();
strUpdate.append("UPDATE INVOICESUMMARY SET ");
int arrSize = columnNames.length;
for (int i=0; i<arrSize;i++){
strUpdate.append(" WHERE InvoiceNumber = " + invoiceNumber + ";");
System.out.println("Update Statement : " + strUpdate.toString());
stmt.executeUpdate(strUpdate.toString());

executing this ID is also changing. except ID and Invoice Number remaining should update.